# disable buttons in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to disable buttons in an aspx form.  This works:

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add(
    "onclick",
    "this.disabled=true;this.value='Saving...';needToConfirm=false;" +
    ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, "").ToString());
```

But there are two buttons on the form and I want to disable both.  This does not work:

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add(
    "onclick",
    "this.disabled=true;this.value='Saving...';document.getElementById(<%=btnDelete.ClientID %>).disableneedToConfirm=false;" +
    ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, "").ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a reference to btnDelete within the btnsave-code here.. You should probably change that to **`btnSave`** :)

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;this.value='Saving...';document.getElementById(<%= btnDelete.ClientID %>).disableneedToConfirm=false;" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, "").ToString());
```

Comment: Oops! the failing line should read: btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;this.value='Saving...';document.getElementById(<%=btnDelete.ClientID %>).disabled=true;needToConfirm=false;" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, "").ToString());

Comment: I'm trying to disable BOTH buttons when one of them is clicked!